# "Shared" bytecode in different architecture slices?

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7, universal-binary, fat-binaries

I have this universal binary which contains two slices (armv7 and armv7s).
I got some simple classes which simply hold some data.
Is it possible to compile these classes so they're only in the binary once instead of once for each slice?
The reason I ask this is that I want to reduce the app's compiled size.

Thanks!

Comment: `I got some simple classes which simply hold some data.` Why wouldn't you use a flat file?

Comment: It better fits my needs like this, I tested various approaches.